# What specific drivers should I install instead of Windows default ones?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, reinstall

I want to reinstall Windows 7, but I don't know what to do with drivers. I built my desktop PC in 2009 and software has piled up, so I want to refresh the system because it seems to crawl sometimes. Why I am required to install drivers if the generic ones just work? How do I recognize performance issues, if I don't know the expected performance? How can I make a list of hardware which need a driver?

Comment: There are many questions here, but, IMO if it's not broke, don't fix it. So if generic works, leave it generic!

Comment: You should either install the manufactor's drivers or the generic drivers.  If both work what you want to do is entirely up to you.

Comment: What I'm asking is if there's a way to obtain a list of hardware on my computer which could need a driver. Before looking on ASUS website, I never thought that there could exist a driver for a chipset!